# Minimising maximum sum algorithm

Tags: algorithms, correctness-proof, optimal-strategy

Given a list of integers ***NUMS*** and an integer ***k*** (buckets), we must allocate every integer from NUMS to some bucket such that *maximum* of sum of integers across all buckets is minimised.

A simple algorithm which first sorts **NUMS** and then allocates integer to smallest bucket so far doesn't work. Eg. 5,5,4,4,4 for k=2. Output is 13 : {5,4}, {5,4,4}, where as correct output is 12 : {5,5}, {4,4,4}.

However, if the input integer array consists of *distinct* integers, will the above algorithm produce correct output? Looking for rigours analysis to understand why/why not.

Answer (score 2):

No. Here is a counterexample (you seem to be sorting integers in decreasing order): $60, 50, 40, 29, 20$ and $2$ buckets. Your algorithm creates one bucket with sum $109$ and one bucket with sum $90$, while there exists a solution having a bucket with sum $99$ and the other with sum $100$.

Besides, if you algorithm worked then it could be used to solve the partition problem in polynomial-time, showing that $\mathsf{P}=\mathsf{NP}$. Indeed, given a set of integers $S$, there is a way to bucket the numbers in $S$ into $2$ buckets with maximum sum $\frac{1}{2} \sum_{x \in S} S$ if and only if the answer to the corresponding partition instance is "yes". Notice that partition [remains NP-hard](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13030/partition-problem-with-distinct-integers) when the integers in $S$ are distinct.

For constant $k$ you can solve your problem in pseudopolynomial time using dynamic programming.
Let $x_1, \dots, x_n$ be the integers in your instance, let $M = \max_{i=1,\dots, n} x_i$, and $\vec{s} = (s_1, s_2, \dots, s_{k-1}) \in \{0, 1, \dots, M\}^{k-1}$.
Call $OPT[i, \vec{s}]$ the minimum possible sum of the elements in the $k$-th bucket when only the first $i$ elements are considered and the sum of the elements in $j$-th bucket with $j < k$ can be at most $s_j$.

Also let $(\vec{s}_{-j}, s'_j)$ denote the vector $\vec{s}$ in which the $j$-th component has been replaced by $s'_j$.

For $i = 0$ and all $\vec{s}$, $OPT[i, \vec{s}] = 0$.

For $i \ge 1$:
$$
OPT[i, \vec{s}] = \min\left\{OPT[i-1, \vec{s}] + x_i, \min_{\substack{j=1,\dots,k-1 \\ x_i \le s_j}} OPT[i-1, (\vec{s}_{-j}, s_j - x_i) ] \right\},
$$
where the minimum over an empty set is $+\infty$.

The value of the optimal solution is:
$$
\min \{ x \mid x \in \{ 0, 1, \dots, M \} \wedge OPT[n, (x, x, \dots, x)] \le x \}.
$$

The optimal solution itself can be recovered by retracing the optimal choices of the minimum backwards.

Comment: Can you give some idea why greedy isn't working?

Comment: I think it is easier to think about it the other way around... why should the greedy algorithm work? Only some very special problems admit greedy algorithms, namely those for which an optimal *local* choice happens to also be an optimal *global* choice. In you case this does not hold, you can eagerly commit one of the numbers to the wrong bucket. In my example $40$ is assigned to the bucket containing $50$, even though it should be in the bucket containing $60$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider `NUMS = [9, 7, 5, 4, 3]` and `k=2`.

Greedy algorithm would return `[9, 4]` and `[7, 5, 3]` which is not optimal, as `[9, 5]` and `[7, 4, 3]` is an optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is equivalent to the problem of scheduling jobs on multiple identical processors in a way that minimizes makespan (when the last job finishes).

This has been shown to be an NP-Hard problem:

> Minimizing the maximum completion time ($P||{\displaystyle C_{\max }}C_{\max }$) is NP-hard even for identical machines, by reduction from the partition problem.
> Many exact and approximation algorithms are known.
> …
> — [Identical-machines scheduling — Minimizing the maximum completion time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identical-machines_scheduling#Minimizing_the_maximum_completion_time_(makespan))

That means that many of the greatest mathematicians in the world have, for many decades, failed to find a good algorithm for your problem.

You might look at some of the suggested algorithms.